# Proof verification of the fact that every open subset of a smooth manifold is a “codimension $0$ submanifold”.

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Suppose that $M$ is a smooth manifold and $O$ is an open subset of $M$. A codimension $k$ submanifold of $M$ is locally defined as the common zero locus of $k$ functionally independent real valued smooth functions $f_1,...,f_k$ on $M$. Is $O$ a codimension $0$ submanifold? 
I know that open subsets of a manifold are manifolds of the same dimension as that of the manifold by restricting the atlas of the manifold. So maybe there is a match between these two notions. In particular, I think that $O$ must be a codimension $0$ submanifold of $M$. Can anyone illustrate this?

I think I found a solution. If there is a functionally independent real valued smooth map on $M$ then it can not take zero on any open subset of $O$ since it would contradict its functional independence.

Comment: Won't that make $O$ a co-dimension $0$ submanifold?

Comment: Of course @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: Where did you see this definition? It's not standard. It implies that every submanifold must be closed, because it's the preimage of the closed set $\{0\}$ under the function $f = (f_1,\dots,f_k)\colon M\to\mathbb R$. In particular, if $M$ is connected, then the only open subsets of $M$ that could be submanifolds by this definition are $M$ and $\emptyset$.

Comment: “More precisely, this means that, for any $p_0$ ∈ $S$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $p_0$ ∈ $M$ and $k$ functionally independent smooth functions
$f_1, . . . , f_k$ : $U$ → $R$ such that $p$ ∈ $U$∩$S$ if and only if $f_1(p)=···=f_k(p)=0$.” This definition is in “lectures on the geometry of manifolds” by Nicolaescu. @JackLee

Comment: Ah, that's very different from what you wrote. You said the functions should be defined on $M$. With this new definition, if $O\subseteq M$ is an open subset, you can just take $U=O$, and consider $O$ as the common zero locus of no functions from $U$ to $\mathbb R$. (The number of functions is supposed to be equal to the codimension, so $k=0$ in this case.)

Comment: Thank you @JackLee

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: By the way, I posted an elementary solution for your only question, which might appeal to you @JackLee